Подскажите пожалуйста, как увеличить кнопки Play и Close при входе через мобильный телефон
/* Normilizes box-sizing  */
#pbOverlay *,
#pbOverlay *:before,
#pbOverlay *:after {
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}


#pbOverlay.show{ opacity:1; pointer-events:auto; }
#pbOverlay{
    opacity:0; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; z-index:9999; left:0; top:0; text-align:center; pointer-events:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.90);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e2000000', endColorstr='#e2000000');
    /* background:radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.9) 100%); */
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0);
    transition:opacity 300ms ease;
}

#pbOverlay.msie{ background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); }
.msie.pbLoading .pbWrapper{ background:url('../images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; }

@keyframes pbLoaderFrames{ 50%{ height:5px; } }
@-webkit-keyframes pbLoaderFrames{ 50%{ height:5px; } }

.pbLoader{ display:none; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; z-index:999; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; margin:auto; text-align:center; border-radius:100%; box-shadow:15px 32px 60px -20px #FFF inset, 1px 1px 3px 1px #FFF inset, 0 0 20px; transition:.3s; }
.thumbs .pbLoader{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-50px); transform:translateY(-50px); }
.pbLoading:not(.msie):not(.error) .pbLoader{ display:block; }
    .pbLoader b{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin:0 2px; width:8px; height:60px; border-radius:5px; background:rgba(255,255,255,.8); box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5); -webkit-animation:.9s pbLoaderFrames infinite linear; animation:.9s pbLoaderFrames infinite linear; }
    .pbLoader b:nth-child(2){ -webkit-animation-delay:.3s; animation-delay:.3s; }
    .pbLoader b:nth-child(3){ -webkit-animation-delay:.6s; animation-delay:.6s; }

.mobile.pbLoading .pbLoader{ transform:none; transition:0s; }

.pbWrapper:after,
#pbCaption .pbThumbs ul:after,
#pbOverlay .prevNext:after,
#pbOverlay .pbLoader:before{ content:""; display:inline-block; height:100%; margin-right:-.25em; vertical-align:middle; }

/* Animation when image was not loaded */
@keyframes deadImage{ 50%{ text-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(255,255,255,.5); transform:scale(.85); } }
@-webkit-keyframes deadImage{ 50%{ text-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(255,255,255,.5); -webkit-transform:scale(.85); } }

#pbOverlay button{ outline:0 !important; box-shadow:0; }


.pbWrapper{ -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; transform:rotate(0deg); vertical-align:middle; height:100%; perspective:1200px; position:relative;  }
.video > .pbWrapper{ z-index:11; display:inline-block; }
    /*#pbOverlay.error .pbWrapper{ display:inline-block; width:100%; }*/
    .pbLoading .pbWrapper{ display:inline-block\9; width:100%; } /* ie8+9 hack */
    .pbWrapper:before{ content:'\2716'; color:transparent; text-shadow:0 2px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0); font-size:0; vertical-align:middle; cursor:default; transition:text-shadow .7s ease-out; }
    .error .pbWrapper:before{ font-size:22em; text-shadow:0 0 0 #FFF; -webkit-animation:2s 1s deadImage infinite linear; animation:2s 1s deadImage infinite linear; }
    .thumbs .pbWrapper{ padding:0; margin:0; }
    .error .pbWrapperr img{ width:0; }

    .pbWrapper > div{ display:none; width:624px; height:351px; vertical-align:middle; border-radius:5px; background:rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
    .video > .pbWrapper > div{ display:inline-block; }

    #pbOverlay iframe,
    #pbOverlay embed,
    #pbOverlay object{ display:block; width:100%; height:100%; opacity:1; transition:.5s; }

    .pbWrapper .pbHide iframe{ opacity:0; }

    .pbWrapper > div,
    .pbWrapper > img{
        transition:.5s .5s cubic-bezier(.1, .87, .48, 1);

        -webkit-transform:none;
        -ms-transform:none;
        transform:none;

        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
        box-shadow:0 0 20px #000;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    /* FOR MOBILE */
    .mobile.show .pbWrapper > div,
    .mobile.show .pbWrapper > img{
        transition:30ms;
    }

    /* Content effects */
    .pbWrapper > *,
    .pbHide .pbWrapper > .prepare{ opacity:0; vertical-align:middle; -webkit-transform:scale(.2) rotateX(80deg); -ms-transform:scale(.2) rotateX(80deg); transform:scale(.2) rotateX(80deg); border-radius:6px; border:none; max-height:95%; max-width:100%; }
    .on .pbWrapper > *{ transition-delay:0s; }
    .pbWrapper .zoomable{ -webkit-transition:0s; transition:0s; position:relative; z-index:9; }
    .pbWrapper .rotating{ -webkit-transition:.25s cubic-bezier(.4,.04,0,1); transition:.25s cubic-bezier(.4,.04,0,1); }
    .pbHide .pbWrapper > *{ -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); transform:scale(1.2); transform:none\9; opacity:0; transition:.4s ease-out; }



/*-- close button --*/
#pbCloseBtn,
#pbAutoplayBtn{ position:absolute; top:-50px; right:-50px; z-index:999; display:block; padding:0 0 20px 20px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; color:#FFF; transition:.3s .3s ease-out; }
.pbHide #pbCloseBtn{ top:-50px; right:-50px; }
.on #pbCloseBtn{ top:-2px; right:-2px; }

#pbCloseBtn:before{ content:'\00D7'; font:bold 1em/1 arial; }
#pbCloseBtn:before, #pbAutoplayBtn:before{ display:inline-block; height:100px; width:100px; padding:8px 8px 12px 12px; font-size:4em; opacity:.8; vertical-align:middle; background:rgba(255,255,255,.2); border-radius:0 0 0 70px; transition:.1s ease-out; }
#pbCloseBtn:hover:before{ padding:15px 10px 24px 24px; background:rgba(255,100,100,.4); }

/*-- autoplay controller --*/
#pbAutoplayBtn{ display:none; right:auto; left:-50px; padding:0; width:100px; height:100px; font-size:13px; }
.hasAutoplay #pbAutoplayBtn{ display:block; }
#pbAutoplayBtn:hover{ width:150px; height:150px; }
.on #pbAutoplayBtn{ top:0px; left:0px; transition:.1s ease-out; }
    #pbAutoplayBtn:before{ content:'\2016'; width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:0 0 70px 0; font-weight:bold; padding:0; text-indent:-6px; line-height:1.6; }
    #pbAutoplayBtn:active:before{ text-shadow:0 0 3px #FFF, 0 0 6px #FFF; }
    #pbAutoplayBtn.play:before{ content:'\25BA'; }

    #pbAutoplayBtn .pbProgress{ display:none\9; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; padding:6px; top:0; left:0; opacity:.2; transform:rotateZ(0deg); -webkit-transform:rotateZ(0deg); -ms-transform:rotateZ(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 0; -ms-transform-origin:0 0; transform-origin:0 0; -webkit-transition:.3s; transition:.3s; }
    .mobile #pbAutoplayBtn .pbProgress{ -webkit-transition:0s; transition:0s; }
    #pbAutoplayBtn.playing .pbProgress{ -webkit-transform:rotateZ(90deg); -ms-transform:rotateZ(90deg); transform:rotateZ(90deg); }
    #pbAutoplayBtn .pbProgress:before{ content:''; position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; width:200%; height:200%; border-radius:50%; box-shadow:0 0 0 8px #FFF inset; }

#pbCaption,
.pbHide #pbCaption{ position:absolute; z-index:999; margin-bottom:5px; bottom:-120px; width:100%; overflow:hidden; transform:translateZ(0px); transition:.4s; }
.show.on #pbCaption{ bottom:0; transition-delay:.5s; }
    #pbOverlay.thumbs #pbCaption label{ display:block; }
    #pbCaption label{ display:none; float:right; margin:0 1em; color:#FFF; opacity:.3; transition:.2s; cursor:pointer; }
    #pbCaption label:after{ content:'\276F'; font-size:30px; line-height:30px; display:inline-block; transform:rotate(-90deg); transition:.2s ease-out; }
    #pbCaption label:hover{ opacity:1; }
    #pbCaption .title,
    #pbCaption .counter{ display:inline-block; color:#FFF; margin:0 6px; }
    #pbCaption .counter{ display:none; opacity:.55; }
    .hasCounter #pbCaption .counter{ display:inline-block; }
    .pbCaptionText{ display:inline-block; transition:.3s; opacity:.9; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5); padding-left:60px; } /* padding-left from <label> */
    .pbCaptionText.change{ -webkit-transform:translateY(25px); transform:translateY(25px); opacity:0; }
    #pbCaption .rotateBtn{ display:none; background:none; border:0; font:800 1.7em/0 Arial; vertical-align:middle; color:rgba(255,255,255,.5); width:1.1em; height:1.1em; padding:0; border-radius:50%; background:rgba(0,0,0,.2); cursor:pointer; transition:.15s ease-out; }
    #pbCaption .rotateBtn.show{ display:block; float:right; }
    #pbCaption .rotateBtn:hover{ color:rgba(255,255,255,.7); }
    #pbCaption .rotateBtn:active{ color:white; background:rgba(0,0,0,.4); }

.mobile #pbCaption label{ display:none; z-index:-1; color:red; }
.mobile .pbCaptionText{ padding:0; }

/* hide thumbnails */
#pbThumbsToggler:checked ~ #pbCaption .pbThumbs{ margin:0; }
#pbThumbsToggler:checked ~ #pbCaption label:after{ transform:rotate(90deg) }
#pbThumbsToggler:checked ~ .pbWrapper{ margin-top:-50px; padding:50px 0; }

.pbThumbs{ display:none; transition:.35s; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; }
.thumbs .pbThumbs{ display:block; width:100%; padding:5px 0 2px; margin-bottom:-100px; overflow:hidden; }
.mobile .pbThumbs{ overflow:auto; }
.pbThumbs:hover{ clear:both; }
    .pbThumbs ul{ display:inline-block; position:relative; list-style:none; height:80px; padding:0 5px; margin:0; white-space:pre; transition:.2s; }
    .pbThumbs ul:after{ vertical-align:bottom; }
        .pbThumbs li{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; height:70%; opacity:.6; text-align:center; position:relative; transition:.15s; }
        .pbThumbs li.active{ height:100%; opacity:1; }
        .pbThumbs li:hover{ height:100%; opacity:1; }
        .pbThumbs li.video::before{ content:'\25BA'; color:#FFF; font-size:20px; height:20px; width:20px; line-height:.9; position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:7px; background:rgba(0,0,0,.4); box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4); border-radius:0 3px 0 0; pointer-events:none; }
            .pbThumbs a{ height:100%; padding:0 2px; display:block; -moz-user-select:none; }
            .pbThumbs li:hover a{  }
                .pbThumbs img{ height:96%; min-height:95.9%; border:2px solid #FFF; max-width:none; border-radius:0; transition:.15s; }
                .pbThumbs li:hover img{ min-height:96%; } /* fix a bug in Chrome and Opera */
                .pbThumbs li.fast a img{ transition:none; }
                .pbThumbs li.active a img{ border-color:#D8FF16; min-height:96%; }

#pbOverlay .prevNext{ display:none; background:rgba(0,0,0,0); position:absolute; z-index:10; height:100%; width:35%; padding:80px 0; opacity:0; box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; top:0; transition:.2s ease-out; text-shadow:0 0 12px #000, 0 0 10px #FFF; user-select:none; filter:alpha(opacity=0); cursor:pointer; }
#pbOverlay.hasArrows .prevNext{ display:block; }
#pbOverlay .prevNext.pbHide{ display:none; }
#pbOverlay.on .prevNext:hover{ opacity:.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50); }
#pbOverlay.on .prevNext:hover:active{ transition:80ms; opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); text-shadow:0 0 16px #FFF, 0 0 10px #000; }
    .prevNext b{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; transition:.2s ease-in; }
    .prevNext:hover b{ transition:.2s cubic-bezier(.095, .870, .485, .985); }
    #pbPrevBtn b{ transform:scale(.4) translateX(350px); -webkit-transform:scale(.4) translateX(350px); }
    #pbNextBtn b{ transform:scale(.4) translateX(-350px); -webkit-transform:scale(.4) translateX(-350px); }
    /* */
    #pbPrevBtn b:before,
    #pbNextBtn b:after{ display:inline; line-height:.3; font-size:18em; font-weight:normal; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial; }

    #pbPrevBtn b:before{ content:'\2039'; }
    #pbNextBtn b:after{ content:'\203A'; }
    /* */
    .on #pbPrevBtn:hover b{ transform:scale(1) translateX(20px); -webkit-transform:scale(1) translateX(20px); }
    .on #pbNextBtn:hover b{ transform:scale(1) translateX(-20px); -webkit-transform:scale(1) translateX(-20px); }

.show #pbPrevBtn, #pbOverlay.show #pbNextBtn{  }
.show #pbPrevBtn{ left:0; text-align:left; }
.show #pbNextBtn{ right:0; text-align:right; }

/*------- media queries (for small screens) -----------*/
@media all and (max-width:700px){
    .pbWrapper img,
    .pbHide .pbWrapper img.prepare{ max-height:100%; }

    .thumbs .pbWrapper{ padding:0; margin:0; }
    .pbThumbs{ margin-bottom:-60px; }
    .pbThumbs.show{ margin:0; }

    .pbThumbs ul{ height:50px; }
        .pbThumbs li{ height:100%; opacity:1; }
        .pbThumbs li img{ min-height:96.5%; }
}
/* fix for Chrome */
@media all and (max-width:710px){
    .pbThumbs li.active a img{ min-height:96%; }
}

Смог увеличить кнопки Play и Close при входе с PC.
с мобильного не попасть в них, очень маленькие.

используй медиа запросы для стилей
@media (max-width: 767px) {
\\ стили для мобильных устройств
}

